# IOS архитектура приложения для просмотра новостей. Как лучше загружать данные из интернета?

Tags: ios

Доброго времени суток! Я делаю приложение для просмотра новостей, превью новостей показывается в  таблице.
Таким образом закачиваю данные:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSString *dataJSON=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:Nil];

    NSData *data=[dataJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *rootDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                   error:nil];
```

И благополучно достаю нужные мне значения, и заношу их в таблицу предпросмотра новостей. 
 Вопрос: Правилен ли такой подход? Или эти данные нужно сначала сохранить где-то на устройстве, а потом добавлять в таблицу? На данном этапе таблица очень сильно лагает, каждая ячейка подгружается, и это затормаживает пролистывание. Не знаю как быть.

### Информацию в ячейку заношу таким образом:

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CellForNews *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    id tempObject=[[NSObject alloc]init];
    tempObject=[self.arrayOfNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.publishDate.text=tempObject[@"date"];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempObject[@"imgPath"]]];
    cell.newsImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.descriptionOfThenews.text=tempObject[@"description"];
    cell.titleOfTheNews.text=tempObject[@"publish_title"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: зависит только от вашей идеологии, если вы хотите долгосрочно кэшировать данные - можете их сохранять например с CoreData, если данные перегружаются при каждом входе на экран = это вполне нормальный вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранять или нет не влияет, лагает у вас все потому что вы грузите все синхронно (dataWithContentsOfURL) т.е. когда вам нужно подгрузить новую ячейку вы лезете в интернет за новой картинкой и вешаете приложение пока не получите ответ. Вместо этого нужно каким -нибудь способом загрузить асинхронно, например, при помощи метода [sendAsynchronousRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10)  NSURLConnection, но тут есть проблема что один запрос может задержаться и картинка отрисуется для предыдущего использования ячейки. Это же кстати верно и для загрузки json, но тут есть вариант что у вас все это работает в фоновом потоке

Ну и просто пара моментов по коду -вы зачем-то делаете лишние действия - грузите json в строку, которую потом перегоняете в NSData хотя можно грузить прямо в NSData, а также создаете лишний пустой объект в строке

```
id tempObject=[[NSObject alloc]init];
```

есть у меня определенные сомнения и по поводу того что вы не создаете новые ячейки (`[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]` переиспользует ячейки, а не создает их, обычно после этой строки проверяют не nil ли вернул этот метод)